# Unable to forward traffic using NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have an application running inside minikube K8 cluster. It’s a simple REST endpoint. The issue is after deployment I am unable to access that application from my local computer.

Using `http://{node ip}:{node port}` endpoint.

However, if I do:

```
kubectl port-forward (actual pod name) 8000:8000
```

The application becomes accessible at: `127.0.0.1:8000` from my local desktop.

Is this the right way?
I believe this isn't the right way? as I am directly forwarding my traffic to the pod and this port forwarding won't remain once this pod is deleted.

What am I missing here and what is the right way to resolve this?

I have also configured a `NodePort` service, which should handle this but I am afraid it doesn’t seem to be working:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rest-api
  name: rest-api-np
  namespace: rest-api-namespace
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8000
  selector:
    app: rest-api


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rest-api
  name: rest-api-deployment
  namespace: rest-api-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-api
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: rest-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: oneImage:latest
        name: rest-api
```

Comment: What's the actual port number you're connecting to?  If you `kubectl describe service rest-api-np`, does it show `Endpoints:` that are connected to the pod?

Comment: how do you get ip address of pod `$ kubectl describe pod test-api` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan you mean IP addresses? By `exec` into pods.

Comment: @DavidMaze ip address of pod ? did you get it ?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it shows the endpoints with an ip address and targetPort.

Comment: Can you update your question with pod yaml so that I can test this myself? Where does your minikube run? What driver it utilizes? Which minikube, kubernetes version?

Comment: @thomas Done. `Minikube v: 1.15.1` and running it on my laptop inside an ubuntu vm. `kubernetes verision: 1.19.0`

Comment: Which vm driver are you using for minikube?

Comment: @thomas Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues because your service is placed in `default` namespace while your deployment is in `rest-api-namespace` namespace.

I have  deploy you yaml files and when the describe the service there were no endpoints:

```yaml
➜  k describe svc rest-api-np 
Name:                     rest-api-np
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=rest-api
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=rest-api
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.111.228
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31668/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Solution for that is to create service in the the same namespace. Once you do that, an ip address and port will appear in the `Endpoints` field:

```yaml
➜ k describe svc -n rest-api-namespace rest-api-np 
Name:                     rest-api-np
Namespace:                rest-api-namespace
Labels:                   app=rest-api
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=rest-api
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.99.49.24
Port:                     <unset>  8000/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32116/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.3:8000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Alternative way is to add [endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) manually:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service # please note that endpoints and service needs to have the same name
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.0.2.42 #ip of the pod 
    ports:
      - port: 8000
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer Thomas, However, it was my mistake above while copying service manifests that i didnt copy the `namespace` line. In real, it belongs to same namespace and as i already mentioned above is also shows enpoint when checked with `describe`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can do port forwarding the rest api service properly connected to your deployment. In that case the service can be resolved using the following way.

First find out the minikube ip

```
minikube ip
```

Then the node port of your service like

```
kubectl get service rest-api-np
```

Once you have these two details just do `http://(minikube-ip):(node-port)`

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, that this isnt working. `I am unable to access that application from my local computer.

Using http://{node ip}:{node port} endpoint.`